# Table has no columns using google charts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I have looked through many posts and tried their suggestions. A new problem arises each time though.

Objective: To create a Google line chart taking data from MYSQL table and encoding it in JSON. From there, I attempt to use an html file to display the chart.

someFile.php:

```
<?php

//connect to the database 
$username = ...;
$password = ...;
$hostname = ...;
$database = ...;

$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";  

//Select database
$db_found = mysqli_select_db($conn,$database);

if($db_found) {
   print "Database Found<br><br>";
}
else{
   print "Database NOT Found<br>";
}


$sql = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM Travel_Test');

if (!$sql) {
   die("Error running $sql: " . mysql_error());
}


$results = array(
'cols' => array (
    array('label' => 'travel_time_date', 'type' => 'datetime'),
    array('label' => 'travel_time_duration', 'type' => 'number')
),
'rows' => array()
);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{

   //date assumes "yyyy - mm -- dd" format
   $dateArr = explode('-', $row['travel_time_date']);
   $year = (int) $dateArr[0];
   $month = (int) $dateArr[1]; //subtract 1 to make compatible with javascript months
   $day = (int) $dateArr[2];

   //time assumes "hh:mm:ss" format
   $timeArr = explode(':', $row['travel_time_timestamp']);
   $hour = (int) $timeArr[0];
   $minute = (int) $timeArr[1];
   $second = (int) $timeArr[2];

   $results['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
      array('v' => "travel_time_date($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second)"),
      array('v' => $row['travel_time_duration'])
   ));      
}

$json = json_encode($results,  JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
echo $json;
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

JSON output:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"travel_time_date","type":"datetime"},
{"label":"travel_time_duration","type":"number"}],
"rows":[{"c":
[{"v":"travel_time_date(2014, 2, 1, 1, 30, 30)"},{"v":55}]},{"c": 
[{"v":"travel_time_date(2014, 2, 1, 2, 30, 30)"},{"v":80}]},{"c":
[{"v":"travel_time_date(2014, 2, 1, 3, 30, 30)"},{"v":60}]},{"c":
[{"v":"travel_time_date(2014, 2, 1, 4, 30, 30)"},{"v":120}]}]}
```

anotherFile.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "http:///Volumes/OS%20X%20Mountain%20Lion/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/traveltrak/travelGraphData.php",
        dataType:"json",
        async: false
        }).responseText;
        //success: function (jsonData) {
            //Create data table out of JSON data loaded from server
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
        //}
    //});
    }
    </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="chart_div"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I tried to preview the page, I checked the developer's console. It states no issues. The error is when the page says: Table has no columns. Any suggestions from here please?

Comment: Try printing the AJAX call's result (`jsonData`) to the console. I think you'll find the (first) issue is with getting the data into a JSON object on your HTML page.

Comment: `console.log(jsonData);` did not make a difference. Still no issues and same problem on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates are not input correctly; the format is `'Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds)'`.  You need to replace "travel_time_date" with "Date":

```
$results['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
    array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second)"),
    array('v' => $row['travel_time_duration'])
));
```

Comment: Alright I fixed that. Along with: ` 'cols' => array( array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'datetime')`    I still receive message: Table has no columns.

Comment: Add the line `console.log(jsonData);` after the AJAX call, then open the page in Chrome and open the developer's console.  What is output there?

Comment: Failed to load resource    http://volumes/.../travelGraphData.php       undefined                  travelGraph.html:20

Comment: That's what I thought.  AJAX can't load data from your local file system, and PHP won't run from your local file system.  You've got the files in XAMPP, just start the XAMPP server and change the URL to match the server (it is probably something like `'http://localhost/traveltrak/travelGraphData.php'`).

Comment: Great, it seems to load the resource now. Although, a new error has replaced it - Error: Invalid JSON string [{.... (It then lists my JSON output) }]  Any idea why?

Comment: Assuming you fixed the dates, your JSON should work: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/65ECL/.

Comment: Error: Invalid JSON string: Connected to MySQL<br>Database Found<br><br>{"cols":[{"label":"Date","type":"datetime"},{"label":"Duration","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 2, 1, 1, 30, 30)"},{"v":55}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 2, 1, 2, 30, 30)"},{"v":80}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 2, 1, 3, 30, 30)"},{"v":60}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 2, 1, 4, 30, 30)"},{"v":120}]}]}   format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js:127

Comment: This JSON string in the error message is different from JSON output from the php file. The output from encoding looks like the one working in your link. The html is not reading it correctly it seems.

Comment: Remove those `echo` and `print` statements from your PHP.  The only thing that file should output is the JSON.

Comment: Still an invalid JSON string. I decided to merge the php and html into one file and run the graph from there and that works. I will just stick with that as I must move on. Thank you very much asgallant.