# Invalid JSON string

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

Hi im trying to make a line chart for my web displaying data from my database in MysQL but i get an inavlidd JSON string error and nothing display this is my code.
I'm using as example the server side code from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

HTML

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
     var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;


var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); //DEFINE DATATABLE

data.addColumn('string', 'Label'); //ADD COLUMN 1
data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); //ADD COLUMN 2
console.log(jsonData);
data.addRows(jsonData); //ADD THE RECEIVED jsonData

// SET OPTIONS
var options = {'title':'REALLY PRETTY PIE CHART',
    'width':400,
    'height':300};

// Instantiate and draw THE chart
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
include_once  'Config.php'; //configuration of my Mysql Database  
$public = 'admin'; //This variable is to select the user i want


try {

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $gsent = $conn->prepare("SELECT estado,Hora FROM Datos Where Usuario LIKE '$public'");
        $gsent->execute();

$resultado = $gsent->fetchAll();
$resultAdoJson = json_encode($resultado);
$resulset = json_decode($resultAdoJson);
$result = array();
$i = 65;
foreach($resulset as $res) {

    $result[] = array(chr($i++), intval($res->estado));
}



print json_encode($result);
}

 catch (PDOException $pe) {

    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());

}

?>
```

The Mysql table only has 3 row for admin with values:

Estado  Hora

- 50         2015-02-16
- 53         2015-02-16
- 10         2015-02-16

This is the JSON i get from the print in the php

```
[{"estado":"50","0":"50","Hora":"2015-02-16","1":"2015-02-16"},  {"estado":"53","0":"53","Hora":"2015-02-16","1":"2015-02-16"},{"estado":"10","0":"10","Hora":"2015-02-16","1":"2015-02-16"}]Array
```

var_dump($resultado)

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { ["estado"]=> string(2) "50" [0]=> string(2) "50" ["Hora"]=> string(10) "2015-02-16" [1]=> string(10) "2015-02-16" } [1]=> array(4) { ["estado"]=> string(2) "53" [0]=> string(2) "53" ["Hora"]=> string(10) "2015-02-16" [1]=> string(10) "2015-02-16" } [2]=> array(4) { ["estado"]=> string(2) "10" [0]=> string(2) "10" ["Hora"]=> string(10) "2015-02-16" [1]=> string(10) "2015-02-16" } }
```

I know that the code display a pie chart, but because i'm a newbie with php and i dont know anything of json or javascript first i want to make the example like the one. How can i convert the result when it works into a line chart?

Comment: The JSON you mentioned is missing ending square bracket "]"

Comment: My bad, bad copy paste the ] is included in the result

Comment: Is it also bad copy past that your JSON ends with keyword Array?

Comment: I think that is for the print i have before the echo, but that its what its displayed in my getData.php

Comment: SO why do you first `print json_encode($resultado );` and then `echo $resultado;`?

Comment: @u_mulder i modify the file to only echo json_encode($resultado) but i get Table has no column in the html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script outputs the word 'Array' next to the JSON string. Remove the line `echo $resultado;` from your PHP script.

EDIT:
Furthermore you have to format your result set as a array of array with ['key', 'value'] structure... For example:

```
[
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
]
```

In your case, change the PHP script (for instance) as follows:

```
$resultado = $gsent->fetchAll();

$result = array();
$i = 65;
foreach($resultado as $res) {

    $result[] = array(chr($i++), intval($res->estado));
}

print json_encode($result);
```

As you can see, I have chosen "estado" for the value and A, B, C  for the labels (realized with `chr($i++)`).

Adapt your JavaScript:

```
// STORE RESPONSE OF THE AJAX REQUEST IN jsonData
var jsonString = $.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

var jsonData = eval(jsonString); //create an javascript array

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); //DEFINE DATATABLE

data.addColumn('string', 'Label'); //ADD COLUMN 1
data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); //ADD COLUMN 2

data.addRows(jsonData); //ADD THE RECEIVED jsonData

// SET OPTIONS
var options = {'title':'REALLY PRETTY PIE CHART',
    'width':400,
    'height':300};

// Instantiate and draw THE chart
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

The result looks like that:

[image: The resulting pie chart]

I hope that helps.

Comment: I remove it but i get Table has no colum error in the html file

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786359/table-has-no-columns-using-google-charts

Comment: You have to format your result set as a array of array with 'key => value' structure... I will edit my post.

Comment: can you post the var_dump of $resultado... The line ``$resultSet = json_encode($resultado);`` is not correct. Use instead ``$resultSet = $resultado``. And please tell me whether it's working.

Comment: I edit the post, that is the result of var_dump($resultado), i still not seeing the chart but the "estado" isn't suppose to be a numeric type not a string? in my mysql is a numeric type

Comment: In your posted JSON snippet estado is defined as string ``{"estado":"50", ...}``. To ensure the GoogleCharts JavaScript gets an integer, I use the function ``intval``. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I tryed your example but i always get table has no column, i leave the same php. When i enter in getdata.php i see this for the print [["A",0],["B",0],["C",0]]

Comment: Ok, i guess that is a problem of the type structure of the resultset. Try to convert the resultset with the following 3 steps: 
 1. fetch the resultset ``$resultado = $gsent->fetchAll();`` 
 2. convert it to a JSON string ``$resultAdoJson =  json_encode($resultAdoJson)`` 
 3. convert the JSON String to a stdClass object ``$resultset = json_decode($resultAdoJson);``. 

Afterwards you can build the result array using the loop, as described in my answer above. After that print out the result array ``print json_encode($result);``.

Comment: Use the resultset array in the foreach loop `foreach($resultset as $res) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the patiente with me, i still getting the table has no column error but now i print this : [["A",50],["B",53],["C",10]], i edit the code of the php

Comment: Ok, now you must add the cols for the data table. Take a look above.

Comment: I change it, but i now i get an Uncaught Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array in the google chrome console

Comment: No i still getting the error, i mark it as good answer because all the work i make you made, but i stillg etting the uncaugh error

Comment: Damn it! Ok, let's try another debug: before the line ``addRows(...)`` insert ``console.log(jsonData);``. The jsonData variable shall be dumped in the browser console. Please post the ouput here. At https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console you find a introduction to work with the browser console.

Comment: I think this is the log: http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=14dhxt5&s=8#.VOoT4HyG-GQ

Comment: The dumped variable is as I expected. It's correct. I don't understand the problem! I guess there is still another error in your JavaScript. I have to take a closer look. Can you upload the ``chart.html``?

Comment: The problem is that the response is a string. But DataTable method addRows expects an array. So we have to convert the string into an array. This job will be done by the `eval` function, which interprets the string. I've changed my answer.

Comment: AMAZING thank you so much, now i can see the chart you are awesome!!